# Any way to reseat a Function object's "this" reference BEFORE constructor invocation?

Tags: javascript

Trying to implement a Javascript sandboxing scheme and now I've run into a bit of a wrinkle. I need to pass a "context" parameter to the code which will essentially serve as a handle to the "global" object, but so far no luck.

To illustrate the problem with a simple example, consider this bit of code:

```
var foo = new Function(" this.baz = this.mux; return this ");
foo.mux = "mux";
foo.call();
console.log(foo.baz);
console.log(foo.toString());
```

Output:

> $> undefined
>
> $> function anonymous() { this.mux; return this; }

It obviously doesn't work because the Function object doesn't seem to get it's own **this** like ordinary functions created with **new**.

So...is there any way to "reseat" a Function's **this** to point to itself beforehand (or just any other way around the issue)?

***EDIT***

Okay, so from what I understand from the comments section I'm going to need a constructed object.

```
var foo = new Function(" return new function(){ this.baz /* = ?? */; return this; } ");
```

Is there a way to somehow access the enclosing anonymous function's properties? Like "this.mux = foo.mux" (except of course "foo" isn't visible from that scope)?

Comment: foo is a function, not an instance of an object.

Comment: You created a function `foo`. You can call that function with `new foo()` if you wanted to. Or `foo.call({mux: 'mux'})`. But having `this` refer to the function object itself is rather unusual. Functions don't work like that (by default), so using the term "reset" here doesn't make sense.

Comment: From your edit it seems you are still confused about how things work. You certainly make it more complicated than what it needs to be. To actually help you, a better explanation of the actual problem and the result you want would help. I believe we are already on the wrong path.

Comment: Sorry yeah, just a beginner in JS and still a little hazy about all the convoluted aspects of the language. I think I've finally grasped the issues at hand here though now, thanks to you guys, so problem solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your getting confused on what `new Function(` does,.  It does not create an instance of an object, it just create a function.   So like any object instances you will also need to use `new` on these.

So you need 2 steps..

1. create the function that you will be creating an object from..
2. with this function create an instance using `new`..

Below is a simple example..

```js
var fcreate = 
  new Function('global', "this.global = global");

var f = new fcreate("hello");

console.log(f.global);
```

If your not bothered about instances, we can forget about `this` altogether, and just create a captured scope as a parameter..

eg..

```js
var f = new Function("global", "console.log(global)");

f("This is a global to function");

f("This is another one");
```

Comment: Hey, that might be the key here! I'll post back soon to see if it works...

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `foo` as a parameter of call:

```
var foo = new Function(" this.baz = this.mux; return this ");
foo.mux = "mux";
foo.call(foo); // <-- this
```

Edit: Although the code above works, I wouldn't recommend it. You will be better off creating the function/class foo:

```
var Foo = function(mux){
    this.baz = mux;
}
var foo = new Foo("mux");
console.log(foo.baz);
```

Comment: Brilliant, works like a charm! Thank you so much, Ibu.

Comment: @SirGalahad  You do realise this is not going to create an instance?  With you using `this`, I would have thought that was the point.

Comment: Right, I was just about to ask about that. So in the above example "mux" actually belongs to the foo prototype, correct? That may not work for me because I really need the code to execute with it's own ***this***.

Comment: @SirGalahad `actually belongs to the foo prototype`  It doesn't even belong to the prototype, it's just a property of the function,.  In javascript functions are objects just like everything else.  eg.  `function test() {}; test.xyz = 1;` here `xyz` is not part of the prototype, it's just a property of the function `test`.  If your wanting your function to have captured scope, like a global,..  just pass it as a parameter, and forget about `this` altogether.  `new Function('global', "console.log(global)")("this is the global");`

Answer (score 1):

The best I could come up with that actually works.

```
var foo = new Function(" this.baz = this.mux; return this ");
var context = { mux: "mux" };
foo = foo.bind(context);

foo();
// context.baz == "mux"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so this is in fact doable, and it's basically an extension of Keith's answer:

```
function verify(condition)
{
    console.log(condition === true ? "pass" : "fail");
}

function test()
{
    if(!(this instanceof test))
        return new test();
    var foo = new Function("mux", "return new function(){ this.baz = mux; return this; } ");
    var bar = new foo(null);
    verify(bar.baz === null);
    var zim = new foo(this);
    verify(zim.baz === this);
    var qud = new foo(global);
    verify(qud.baz === global);
};

test();
```

Output:

> pass
>
> pass
>
> pass

A sincere thanks to everyone for helping me figure this one out - cheers!

*** EDIT ***

As per Keith's comments, the correct implementation would simply be:

```
function verify(condition)
{
    console.log(condition === true ? "pass" : "fail");
}

function test()
{
    if(!(this instanceof test))
        return new test();
    var foo = new Function("mux", "this.baz = mux; return this; ");
    var bar = new foo(null);
    verify(bar.baz === null);
    var zim = new foo(this);
    verify(zim.baz === this);
    var qud = new foo(global);
    verify(qud.baz === global);
};

test();
```

Comment: This is even more confusing. You are essentially calling `new function(mux) { return new function() { this.baz = mux; return this;}}`, which can be simplified to `new function(mux) { this.baz = mux;}`, which in your case would mean `new Function("mux", "this.baz = mux;")`.

Comment: You're right, I was making it more complicated than it needed to be. So Keith's answer was actually correct after all. Thanks for setting me straight Felix!